# java.lang.NullPointerException at android.content.ContextWrapper.getPackageName

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, maps

> Hi guys , I am sending my current Latitude and Longitude from MainActivity to Another Class,but everytime the code is executed I get a Null Pointer Error.
>
> Here is my Main Activity :

```
 public String getLocationName() {
    String streetaddress = null;

    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(MainActivity.this);

    try {
        List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(lastLocation.getLatitude(), lastLocation.getLongitude(), 1);
        if (addresses.size() > 0) {
            Address address = addresses.get(0);
            streetaddress = address.getAddressLine(0);
            Log.e("StreetAddress", String.valueOf(streetaddress));
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return streetaddress;
}
```

> This method is working fine in MainActivity, but in another class as I access this method the App crashes.
>
> Here is how I am accessing this method :

```
   MainActivity mainActivity = new MainActivity();

        String Z = mainActivity.getLocationName();
        Log.e("Z here", Z );
```

Comment: **Never** create an instance of an `Activity` or `Service` yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Use the LocationManager.

```
       LocationManager lm = 
              (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE); 
        Location location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
       double longitude = location.getLongitude();
      double latitude = location.getLatitude();


     private final LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
     public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
       longitude = location.getLongitude();
    latitude = location.getLatitude();
             }
        }

       lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 2000, 10, 
       locationListener);
```

You'll need to give your application the ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission if you want to use GPS.

```
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

You may also want to add the ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION permission for when GPS isn't available and select your location provider with the getBestProvider() method.